# prefuse axis title

Tags: title, prefuse

How does one go about giving a title to the axis in prefuse scatter plot?

At the moment my code reads the data from the file and a range for both x and y axis works in the code. All I need to do now is to add titles/names for the axis. The code I have at the moment shows:

```
//set up the actions
AxisLayout xaxis = new AxisLayout(group, "GD",
Constants.X_AXIS, VisiblePredicate.TRUE); 

AxisLayout yaxis = new AxisLayout(group, POINTS,
Constants.Y_AXIS, VisiblePredicate.TRUE);

//yaxis.setScale(Constants.LOG_SCALE);
yaxis.setRangeModel(receiptsQ.getModel());
receiptsQ.getNumberModel().setValueRange(0,120,0,120);

xaxis.setLayoutBounds(m_dataB);
yaxis.setLayoutBounds(m_dataB);

// sets group,axis,values,bounds 
AxisLabelLayout ylabels = new AxisLabelLayout("ylab", yaxis, m_ylabB);
NumberFormat nf= NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
ylabels.setNumberFormat(nf);

// AxisLabelLayout xlabels = new AxisLabelLayout("goal diff", xaxis, m_xlabB, 15);
AxisLabelLayout xlabels = new AxisLabelLayout("xlab",xaxis,m_xlabB,5);

// vis.putAction("xlabels", xlabels);
vis.putAction("xlabels", xlabels);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it by hand. I've done this and my code is open source, so you're welcome to take a look at it:

https://github.com/brycecr/msmexplorer/blob/acacia/MSMExplorer/src/edu/stanford/folding/msmexplorer/util/axis/AxisRotateRenderer.java

https://github.com/brycecr/msmexplorer/blob/acacia/MSMExplorer/src/edu/stanford/folding/msmexplorer/util/axis/AxisLabelLabelLayout.java

In the label renderer, all the labels are drawn as a combination of a line and a label. In this class, we just add an additional item to the layout with our graph.

This is not super clean at all...in particular, a line (actually one pixel) is still rendered for the label, but I'm lazy and this suits my needs...I think you could improve this if necessary, but you'd probably need to reach into the axis renderer and make it draw no line for your label items.

Let me know if you have any questions about the operation of this.

```
    @Override
    public void run(double frac) {
        super.run(frac);

        setLabPos(item, length/2.0d + width, bounds);
    }

    /**
     * Set the layout values for an axis label item.
     */
    protected void setLabPos(VisualItem item, double xOrY, Rectangle2D b) {
        switch (getAxis()) {
            case Constants.X_AXIS:
                xOrY = super.isAscending() ? xOrY + b.getMinX() : b.getMaxX() - xOrY;
                PrefuseLib.updateDouble(item, VisualItem.X,  xOrY);
                PrefuseLib.updateDouble(item, VisualItem.Y,  b.getMaxY() + label.getFont().getSize()/3.0d + gridLab.getFont().getSize());
                PrefuseLib.updateDouble(item, VisualItem.X2, xOrY);
                PrefuseLib.updateDouble(item, VisualItem.Y2, b.getMaxY() + label.getFont().getSize()/3.0d + gridLab.getFont().getSize());
                break;
            case Constants.Y_AXIS:
                xOrY = super.isAscending() ? b.getMaxY() - xOrY - 1 : xOrY + b.getMinY();
                PrefuseLib.updateDouble(item, VisualItem.X,  b.getMinX());
                PrefuseLib.updateDouble(item, VisualItem.Y,  xOrY);
                PrefuseLib.updateDouble(item, VisualItem.X2, b.getMinX());
                PrefuseLib.updateDouble(item, VisualItem.Y2, xOrY);
        }
    }
   }
```